# Type error when using a parser in Python

Tags: python

I have the following html parser:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []

    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)

    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

I would like to use this on the following data.frame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([['<br> test </br>', 1]], columns=('body', 'ticketID'))
```

My assumption would be that it would work like this:

```
 for row in df.iterrows():
     input = row['body']
     print(strip_tags(input)
```

But this gives me a type error. Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Comment: Can you please add _whole_ error message?

Comment: @Frits Please be more generous, use 4 spaces for indentation. 1 space is too low.

Comment: Include an input and output.

Answer (score 1):

**From the ([Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)):**

> DataFrame.iterrows()
>
> ```
> Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.
> ```

So you get the index, along with the row.

**Working Code:**

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    input = row['body']
    print(strip_tags(input))
```